# PHP & MySQL email verify not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem. I made registration with email verification on my website. It was working two days ago, but yesterday it stopped working. I tryied to change to code, but nothing happened. The problem is that the code didn't find any matches. Here is code:

```
    ob_start();
 require_once 'include/connect.php';
 $pripojenie=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($pripojenie);
 if(isset($_GET['tokenCode'])){
    $token = $_GET['tokenCode'];
    $query = "UPDATE users SET userStatus='Y' WHERE tokenCode='$token'";
    if($dbcon->query($query)){
            //odoslať email
        $to=$_GET['userEmail'];
        $subject='Účet aktivovaný';
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <noreply@limix.eu>' . "\r\n";
        $text="<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>Ahoj!<br><br>Ďakujem za aktiváciu účtu na webovej stránke <a href='http://limix.eu'>LiMix.eu</a>.<br><br>S pozdravom<br>Maximilián Csank
        </body>
        </html>";
        mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers);
        header('Location: index.php?error=4');
        exit();

 }
 //ak je už aktívny, presmerovať na chybu
 } else if ($row['userStatus']=='Y') {
    header('Location: index.php?error=7');
    exit();
} else {
//ak je zlý token, presmerovať na chybu
header('Location: index.php?error=5');
exit();
 }
```

What's wrong with this code? Thanks.

**EDIT**
I've got another code, which is mine, but it wasn't working so I commented it.

```
$mail=$row['userEmail'];
  $toke=$row['tokenCode'];
  $token=isset($_GET['$toke']);
  $email=isset($_GET['$mail']);
  $query="UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE tokenCode='$token', 
  userEmail='$email'";
  if ($dbcon>query($query)){
    header('Location: index.php?error=4');
  }
```

Comment: what is your token code and how query is making `echo $query = "UPDATE user....` ?

Comment: `mysql_query`, `$dbcon->query`. Why?

Comment: I don't get what is the purpose of this 2 lines in your code? `$pripojenie=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");$row=mysql_fetch_array($pripojenie);`. It will retrieve only one row and that too of some other record. What are you trying to accomplish? **NOTE:** You are mixing mysql and PDO

Comment: @VedPrakash i don't get any error. It moves me to index.php?error=7, which displays that account is actived yet.

Comment: If this line is executing `header('Location: index.php?error=7');`. It means, `if(isset($_GET['tokenCode'])){` is not working. `tokenCode` is not coming to this page.

Comment: After registration an email is sent to account email. There is url with token, which is added to user in MySQL. And in this verify, the code has to find tokenCode from URI, which is in MySQL table (the code is connected to MySQL). And then when it finds the tokenCode in table, it finds the profile with than tokenCode and changes in table for that user active from 0 to 1

Comment: I saw `$to=$_GET['userEmail'];`. So, email is also passed in URL? Right??

Comment: Yes, it is, because I had a problem with automatic generated token

Comment: Post full code of this page. seems something missing.

Comment: the line `$token=isset($_GET['$toke']);` will return either true or false - which means that your sql would say `UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE tokenCode='true|false', 
  userEmail='$email'`

Comment: @RamRaider thank, I didn't know it. I'm just learning in MySQL and PHP.

Comment: @AnkitSingh it is full code.

Comment: Do you want to send email again after verification successful?

Comment: Your sql is vulnerable to SQL injection and the email contains a hyperlink without any querystring ~ surely there should be the token in that querystring??

Comment: @AnkitSingh yes, that account is activated. And RamRaider, the token is there [screen from pma](http://imgur.com/rsy5v02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how you should be able to validate the user email address by sending an email with a hyperlink that contains the token - you do not need to include the email address in any links sent.

Assuming that the email you generate contains a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/verify.php?token=$token'>Click here to verify registration</a>
```

and using simple functions to generate/test the token - like this:

```
function createtoken( $email, $key ){
    return hash_hmac( 'ripemd160', sha1( $email ), $key );
}
function verifyemail( $email, $token, $key ){
    return createtoken( $email, $key )===$token;
}


/* define a secret used to hash the email address prior to sending email */
define( 'SECRET_KEY', sha1('This is ever so secret and never changes') );
```

Then to process the user activation

```
/* verify.php */
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['token'] ) ){
    try{
        /* Get the token from the URI */
        $token=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'token', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'xxx'; 
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


        /* assume $db is a mysqli connection */
        $sql='select distinct `email` from `users` where `token`=? and `userstatus`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $status=0;
            $stmt->bind_param( 'si', $token, $status );
            $result=$stmt->execute();

            if( $result ){

                /* Store the result & bind column to variable BEFORE getting `num_rows` */
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $email );

                /* Fetch number of rows from db as integer ~ there should be only 1 at most */
                $rows=$stmt->num_rows;

                /* Fetch the result into the variable & tidy up */
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->free_result();                   
                $stmt->close();


                if( $rows==1 ){

                    /* Token was found - validate and update db */
                    if( verifyemail( $email, $token, SECRET_KEY ) ){

                        $sql='update `users` set `userstatus`=? where `token`=?';

                        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                        if( $stmt ){
                            /*
                                in my test table `users`, the column `userstatus` is set as `tinyint(1)`
                                so 1=yes/true and 0=no/false rather than string yes/no
                            */
                            $yes=1;
                            $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $yes, $token );
                            $result = $stmt->execute();

                            if( $result ){
                                $rows = $db->affected_rows;
                                if( $rows===1 ){
                                    $status=@mail( $email, 'success', 'email validated' );

                                    exit( header( 'Location: /login?validated='.$status ) );
                                }
                            } else {
                                throw new Exception('unable to update record',5);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception('unable to verify email',4);
                    }
                } else {
                    /* Token cannot be found */
                    throw new Exception('Invalid token',3);
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('query failed',2);
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('unable to prepare sql statement',1);
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( header( 'Location: /index.php?error='.$e->getCode().'&message='.$e->getMessage() ) );
    }
}
```

--

It is the value of `$token` that needs to be both recorded in the database ( for same record as user's email address ) and used in the hyperlink which is sent in the HTML email.

```
define( 'SECRET_KEY', sha1('This is ever so secret and never changes') );

$token = createtoken( 'fred.bloggs@yahoo.com', SECRET_KEY ); /* yields: c6bc1ba4a8193cd965f1175197b5170c4c385040 */
```

A basic example `users` table:

```
mysql>describe users;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default          | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL             | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(64)         | NO   | MUL | NULL             |                |
| email      | varchar(64)         | NO   | MUL | mail@example.com |                |
| token      | varchar(64)         | NO   | MUL | default_token    |                |
| userstatus | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+

/* add the user */
mysql>insert into `users` (`username`,`email`,`token`) values ('fred.bloggs','fred.bloggs@yahoo.com','c6bc1ba4a8193cd965f1175197b5170c4c385040');

/*

    It would be at this point ( adding user to db ) that you generate the email to the user with a confirmation link that they must click. 
    The status is set to zero / no so they should not be able to login until that is updated.

    The above is the equivalent of the user clicking "submit" after completing the form for example

*/

mysql> select * from users;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+
| id | username    | email                 | token                                    | userstatus |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | fred.bloggs | fred.bloggs@yahoo.com | c6bc1ba4a8193cd965f1175197b5170c4c385040 |          0 |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+
```

The user clicks the link in his/her email and is taken to the `verify.php` page ( for example ) and the querystring `https://www.example.com/verify.php?token=c6bc1ba4a8193cd965f1175197b5170c4c385040` contains the `token` - so at this point the verification starts with the code posted previously.

You tend not to see such a simplified url when it comes to validation - but in essence this is what is happening. The actual url that is provided for the user to click would probably be much more complicated as some might consider the above mechanism easy to break ( should they get to see the email to begin with )

I hope that helps a little in getting your registration confirmation working ~ as you didn't share the portions of code that generate the token, record to db or send the email to the user it can only be offered as guidance rather than the actual answer but certain portions of it ( namely the prepared statements approach ) should be adopted/adapted to your code to prevent naughty people hacking your db ;-)

Comment: thanks, but getCode(), I don't have specified errorcodes, I put it manually. How to specify it?

Comment: I made a small mistake by calling `$stmt->num_rows` before calling `$stmt->store_result()` etc so it always returned zero. Altered the sql slightly to only select the user's email if token matched that supplied and also if `userstatus` is zero (ie: not already validated ) ~ other than that it seemed to work so can you clarify where it failed for you?

Comment: It doesn't find a match. And $token is token, which has to be sent in email and added to DB? Or is it $key?

Comment: Please, can you send me full verify code, which is correct :)